# Trouble reading a tab separated file from an API in R

Tags: r

When entering a URL to an API I get a .csv file in a .gz download.
The data in the TAB separated .csv file looks like this (the first six lines):

```
00031483    "youtube.com"   "2015-05-18 13:31:06"   26
00031483    "youtube.com/channel/UCgfzulPx4-ef6oOX6Jj6f9"   "2015-05-18 13:31:32"   16
00031483    "youtube.com/watch?v=Qj8dEBHzev"    "2015-05-18 13:31:48"   16
00031483    "youtube.com/my_videos?o="  "2015-05-18 13:32:04"   5
00031483    "youtube.com/my_videos?o="  "2015-05-18 13:32:09"   9
00031483    "youtube.com/edit?o=U&video_id=e-Yn8BTZTx"  "2015-05-18 13:32:18"   40
```

When I try to read the file automatically from the API in R with for instance:

```
read.table(PageViewsURL, sep="\t", quote='"', header = FALSE)
```

I am getting the following error message:

```
  Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
     line 1 did not have 2 elements
  In addition: Warning messages:
     1: In read.table(PageViewsURL, sep = "\t", quote = "\"", header = FALSE) :
  line 1 appears to contain embedded nulls
     2: In read.table(PageViewsURL, sep = "\t", quote = "\"", header = FALSE) :
  line 5 appears to contain embedded nulls
```

Downloading the file and unzipping it by: `download.file(PageViewsURL, paste("E:/Pageviews_", substr(GMTtime,1,10), ".gz", sep=""))` delivered me a .gz file with a file without extension giving me the same trouble reading it.

Does anyone have a clou how to read in the file? 
It is quite big, 667464 lines.

Unfortunately I am not able to share the API url or the file because of privacy matters. I also altered the given URL's because of this.

Comment: Try to read the first few lines with `readLines(PageViewsURL,10)` to see if every field is separated by `\t`.

Comment: Thanx Nicola. In every line the tabs were rightly inserted, but the URL's seemed to have characters which were dividing records in more then the official number of columns.     >fill=TRUE     helped overcome my problems.